# Extract output of Juniper Devices and save to dictionary file via netmiko python

Tags: python, csv, ssh, juniper

I run my script using netmiko and ssh to juniper device. The script run commands to get device info such as hostname, model, etc. The output then is save onto dictionary.

print output result from code got too many space and output not properly save onto dictionary

This is the print output result from the code

```
Hostname: vcx.lab01

{master}

Model: t640

{master}

Junos: 15.1R7-S1

{master}
```

If you can see above, there is a a lot of space/gaps between first command output and second command output and each command will end with {master}.

Below is the output key-in cli direct from Juniper router

```
usr12@vcx.lab01> show version | match Hostname
Hostname: vcx.lab01

{master}

usr12@vcx.lab01> show version | match Model
Model: t640

{master}

usr12@vcx.lab01> show version | match Junos:
Junos: 15.1R7-S1

{master}
```

Even I'm getting the same space issues when run the same commands over the juniper router.

Thus when I save each of the output of juniper device to my dictionary it will save like below

```
Hostname,Model,Version^M
"
Hostname: vcx.lab01

{master}","
Model: t640

{master}","
Junos: 15.1R7-S1

{master}"^M
```

I would like the print output to be clean no space and no {master} like below

```
Hostname: vcx.lab01
Model: t640
Version: 15.1R7-S1
```

and I would like dictionary file as below

```
Hostname,Model,Version
vcx.lab01,t640,15.1R7-S1
```

I really need your help to advise me what can I do to overcome this issues, please help me. Thanks

Comment: Hi, still no luck...anyone can advise further. I cannot use PyEZ as the devices does not netconf enable and unfortunately to enable this features is beyond my control. Thus, the only way for now is using connection.send_command(). Get and extract require data and try to save it in the dict. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just to share the solution

I use re.sub() and string slicing and able to to get clean data line by line without any empty space and {master} state.

Thank you. I hope this could help others also.